# Chef wrapper cookbooks and attribute precedence. Attributes being ignored?

Tags: chef-infra

I have a policy cookbook dw_gpfs with the following dependencies:

- dw_gpfs depends on global_base.
- global_base depends on unix_base.
- unix_base depends on tsm (This is the IBM Spectrum Protect backup/restore product).
  The run-list for includes is the same order.

The TSM cookbook has attributes for building the configuration files for the application.
One of them in particular ['gpfs_backup'] is set to false in one of the TSM attributes file, and there is subsequent logic in the same file that determines what the app config files look like based on the truth value of ['gpfs_backup'].

The issue is that when I set default['tsm']['gpfs_backup'] = true in the dw_gpfs cookbook, the logic in the tsm cookbook isn't triggered.  I've tried normal, and force_default to no avail.  The environment in this particular case is a local kitchen using Docker and RHEL7.  If I add the -D param to the kitchen converge command, I see the attribute data where that attribute is indeed set to true.  So why isn't the logic in the dependent cookbook triggered for that value being true?  This seems like some sort of timing issue.  What am I missing?  I can provide code snippets to clarify if needed.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 factors to take into account:

1. [attribute precedence](https://docs.chef.io/attributes/#attribute-precedence)
2. [recipe\cookbooks run-list](https://docs.chef.io/run_lists/)

now each of which can be manipulated dynamically, it might add even more things to take into account...

with that being said, if you are familiar with the chef concept above, then review your code to reveal what causes the inconsistency that you depict.

you might also with to consider running [chef-client with higher log level](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client/) by appending `--log_level debug` to chef-client executable.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own problem.  This is the "derived attributes" issue seen elsewhere.

Comment: You should describe the solution and accept your own answer here.